# Razor editor crashes VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, razor, editor

I have VS2010 ultimate installed on W7x64.  I recently installed SP1 and  MVC3.  Everything seemed fine until I tried to edit a view(cshtml). VS crashed.  Any time I try to edit a view with the Razor editor, VS will exit - sometimes after a pause and sometimes instantly.  I can "edit with" the HTML editor, but not razor.

The jit debugger gives: an unhandled win32 exception in devenenv.exe [11572].

When I choose to debug I get: Unhandled exception at 0x76e3139d in devenv.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000.

this repeats until I break at which time I am shown a disassembly.

Any help for this?

Thanks.

Comment: Reinstall MVC or in the worst case reinstall VS2010.

Comment: I uninstalled mvc3 and reinstalled with no luck.  Maybe a reinstall of VS is in order.  Thanks

Comment: Try disabling your extensions too, and reenabling them one by one.

Comment: Anything specific in VS logs? Try `devenv /Log c:\vs.log`

Answer (score 0):

In this Cases we have following Possibilities:

1. VS is not installed correctly(don't try to reinstall or uninstall the install because VS doesn't accept this trip and has no more good effect) perhaps in installing compilers and etc. So, there is no way unless clear->install windows.
2. Installing some extensions cause the problem. So, try confident extension.
3. Disturbing OS or VS necessary files by Virus.Repairing is not complete solution.
4. MVC extension is not installed or configured truly.

Not that Compiler issues are more complicated than other software issues. 
You can also participate in VS community to develop and debug this product or send error information to Microsoft corporation.